# React Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in React reading id path variable from React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, react-props

I am trying to pass in a path variable, userId, as a prop to a React component rendered by React Router:

Profile.js

```
export const Profile = (props) => {

//array of compatible users fetched for a user.
const [userProfileInformation, setUserProfileInformation] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    getUserProfileInformation().then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    });
}, []);

const getUserProfileInformation = async () => {
    //Currently hardcoded value until authorisation implemented.
    const userId = this.props.match.params.id;
    const response = await UserService.getUserProfileInformation(userId)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            setUserProfileInformation(data);
        });
}

if (isLoading) {
    return (
        <div id="loading">
            <h2>Loading...</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

return (
<div>
    <div className="profileCard">
        <h2>{userProfileInformation.email}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
)
```

}

The error occurs because of the 'userId = props.match.params.id' code.

App.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
document.getElementById("root")
```

);

```
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
            <Route path="/profile/:userId" element={<Profile />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Dashboard.js:

```
export const Dashboard = () => {
return(
    <div>
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
        <Button color="link"><Link to={`/profile/1`}>Profile</Link></Button>
    </div>
);
```

}

The above temporarily uses a hardcoded value for the link, 1.

Edit:

Tried with `const userId = props.match.params.id;` and `const userId = this.props.match.params.id` and `const userId = props.match.params.userId;` and `const userId = this.props.match.params.userId;`

All give same result as before.

Thanks

Comment: You're using `this.props.match.params.id` which should just be `props.match.params.id` (depending on which React Router version you're using).

Comment: @Chris I have updated the question, I have tried with both this and without this and same result.

Comment: @HasanRiza I have updated the question, I have tried with both id and userId, thanks.

Comment: The particular error would only come when you use `this` because you are using a functional component. It is trying to access `props` in the `this` object, which does not exist. You need to use `props.match.params.userId` and then tell us what the new error is.

Comment: @HasanRiza Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
    at getUserProfileInformation (Profile.js:24:1)
    at Profile.js:17:1                                                                                                                  and the line 24 of Profile.js =   const userId = props.match.params.userId;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of react-router-dom you are using is v6. In this version (which has lots of breaking changes you need to keep an eye out for), the `params` object is not accessible since `route props` are not passed to the `element`/component.

In order to access the `userId`, you now need to use the `useParams` hook.

1. Import it: `import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'`
2. In place of `const userId = props.match.params.userId`, use `const { userId } = useParams()` and then use it like you did before.

If this answer helps, please accept it. Thanks!